# How do I hide a table column in a view depending on role?

Tags: views, 8

I have created a View that outputs a table with an edit column (that has a link to edit the item for that row). When you hare logged in as an administrator, you see the column and the edit links as I would like. However, when viewing the table as an anonymous user, the edit column still appears even though the edit links are not being displayed. I would like the entire edit column to be hidden from all users who do not have the role to view them.

I thought I might be able to hide the column if I set the table settings to hide column if there is no output, but that didn't work. I suspect it didn't work because there was output, but its display is being suppressed by the users role. Can someone confirm if that is how it is supposed to work (it may be a bad assumption on my part)?

I have tried Googling for a solution to this, but I can't find any solution that applies to Drupal 8 (only Drupal 6 and 7).

Thanks.

Comment: Here is a hint, you could use [template_preprocess_views_view_table](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_views_view_table/8.4.x)